# Default AES key in Websphere liberty

Tags: websphere, aes, websphere-liberty

in case of AES encryption of passwords in websphere liberty sever.xml, if default key is being used in securityUtility command, means wlp.password.encryption.key is not being setup in server.xml to override default key, then is the default aes key kept anywhere on any config file or key is hidden , anyway to find default key. I am asking this as someone working earlier, encrypted keys in our dev env using default aes key, and now I need to decrypt those to check correctness of some passwords.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default aes encoding key is not stored in any config file. Rather than worry about what the default encoding key is, or how the encryption key was defined and the format of the aes block I would suggest you instead write some code that runs in the Liberty server that doesn't have the encoding key specified and use the [PasswordUtil](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.liberty.doc/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.passwordUtil_1.0-javadoc/com/ibm/websphere/crypto/PasswordUtil.html) decode method to decode it.